# How to lock NFC tag after writing on it?

Tags: android

I am using NFC tags to write a student ID on it then to be read by my application,

How I can prevent any user to rewrite over the tag ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it when I tried, but this is not reversible, you can only do it once, so be careful.

```
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);  
    if (ndef != null) { 
        ndef.makeReadOnly();
    }
```